# Is there a way in mfc slider control that as i move the thumb, it fills the background color of the slider over the default background color

Tags: c++, background, mfc, slider, customization

I am trying to make a customised slider in mfc.Is there a way so that as I move the slider, the background color changes according to the position of the thumb of the slider over the default background color, just like the default .net slider in .net.

```
void rogreen::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting
                       // TODO: Add your message handler code here
                       // Do not call CStatic::OnPaint() for painting messages

    CRect rectWindow;
    GetClientRect(&rectWindow);


    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);

    int r1 = { 0 }, g1 = { 255 }, b1 = { 0 }; //Any start color
    int r2 = { 0 }, g2 = { 0 }, b2 = { 0 }; //Any stop color

    for (int i = 0;i < rect.Height();i++)
    {
        int r, g, b;
        r = r1 + (i * (r2 - r1) / rect.Height());
        g = g1 + (i * (g2 - g1) / rect.Height());
        b = b1 + (i * (b2 - b1) / rect.Height());
        dc.FillSolidRect(0, i, rect.Width(), 1, RGB(r, g, b));
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, the color interpolation code is wrong. It assumes a linear color space, and RGB is not a linear color space (see [Everything you know about colour is wrong](https://youtu.be/_zQ_uBAHA4A) for details).

Comment: You may want to look into `CDC::GradientFill` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdc-class?view=msvc-170#gradientfill instead of drawing line-ny-line

Answer (score 3):

Using the example from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/drawing-a-shaded-rectangle, you can handle a `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` message like that:

```
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
{
    if (::GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_SLIDER) == (HWND)lParam) {
        HDC hdc = (HDC)wParam;
        RECT r = {};
        ::GetClientRect((HWND)lParam, &r);
        
        // Create an array of TRIVERTEX structures that describe 
        // positional and color values for each vertex. For a rectangle, 
        // only two vertices need to be defined: upper-left and lower-right. 
        TRIVERTEX vertex[2];
        vertex[0].x = 0;
        vertex[0].y = 0;
        vertex[0].Red = 0x0000;
        vertex[0].Green = 0x8000;
        vertex[0].Blue = 0x8000;
        vertex[0].Alpha = 0x0000;

        vertex[1].x = r.right; // 400;
        vertex[1].y = r.bottom; // 40;
        vertex[1].Red = 0x0000;
        vertex[1].Green = 0xd000;
        vertex[1].Blue = 0xd000;
        vertex[1].Alpha = 0x0000;

        // Create a GRADIENT_RECT structure that 
        // references the TRIVERTEX vertices. 
        GRADIENT_RECT gRect;
        gRect.UpperLeft = 0;
        gRect.LowerRight = 1;
        // Draw a shaded rectangle. 
        GradientFill(hdc, vertex, 2, &gRect, 1, GRADIENT_FILL_RECT_V);
        return (INT_PTR)::GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
    }
}
```

You can use your slider's position to calculate the color values you want.

Comment: @Nasim - please don't keep us in suspense! :) Did that work?

Comment: I couldn't make it work, unfortunately, actually, I need a slider that changes the background color of the slider as the thumb moves. is it possible to make such a customizable slider?

Comment: @Nasim - sure; in the function above, you can get the slider position first and set colors (`vertex[0].Red = 0x0000` etc.) based on that.